Creating Blank Link Messages in Telegram: Word Joiner vs. Soft Hyphen
In Telegram, there are situations in which I prefer to create a link without displaying the link text, allowing only the link preview to be visible.

To achieve this, I can use two characters as the link text:

Word joiner: U+2060 [⁠](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78339665/478018)
Soft hyphen: U+00AD [­](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78339665/478018)

Which option is more reliably supported across different platforms and devices, and less likely to be affected by future Telegram updates?


Both are not clickable links 2) We don't know what Telegram might update


@0stone0: "Both are not clickable links" What link did you use? Please try a link of which Telegram displays the preview, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78339665/478018

Ahh, now it makes sense that' you're using the preview thingy. That works fine! Still not sure what you're expecting as an answer here.

@0stone0: "Still not sure what you're expecting as an answer here." Which of the above characters would you use as the link text?

None of these, it's probably not a supported route by Telegram and thus prone to change/break. It's also not handy for supportive tools, like some people with bad vision might let there phone read there conversation, which will probably say something weird when encountering your link. Also on iPhone app there is still an empty line shown, that's not there on Android so it's not consistent.

@0stone0: "Also on iPhone app there is still an empty line shown, that's not there on Android so it's not consistent." Do both characters cause this behavior?

Yep, iPhone shows a empty line at both's chars where android does not.
